# Ugly Number - Mathematical intuition for dp

Tags: algorithm

I am trying find the "ugly" numbers, which is a series of numbers whose only prime factors are [2,3,5].

I found dynamic programming solution and wanted to understand how it works and what is the mathematical intuition behind the logic.

1. The algorithm is to keep three different counter variable for a multiple of 2, 3 and 5. Let's assume i2,i3, and i5.
2. Declare ugly array and initialize 0 index to 1 as the first ugly number is 1.
3. Initialize i2=i3=i4=0;
4. ugly[i] = min(ugly[i2]*2, ugly[i3]*3, ugly[i5]*5) and increment i2 or i3 or i5 which ever index was chosen.

Dry run:

```
ugly = |1|

  i2=0;
  i3=0;
  i5=0;

ugly[1] = min(ugly[0]*2, ugly[0]*3, ugly[0]*5) = 2

---------------------------------------------------

ugly = |1|2|

  i2=1;
  i3=0;
  i5=0;

ugly[2] = min(ugly[1]*2, ugly[0]*3, ugly[0]*5) = 3

---------------------------------------------------

ugly = |1|2|3|

  i2=1;
  i3=1;
  i5=0;

ugly[3] = min(ugly[1]*2, ugly[1]*3, ugly[0]*5) = 4

---------------------------------------------------

ugly = |1|2|3|4|

  i2=2;
  i3=1;
  i5=0;

ugly[4] = min(ugly[2]*2, ugly[1]*3, ugly[0]*5) = 5

---------------------------------------------------

ugly = |1|2|3|4|5|

  i2=2;
  i3=1;
  i5=1;

ugly[4] = min(ugly[2]*2, ugly[1]*3, ugly[0]*5) = 6

---------------------------------------------------

ugly = |1|2|3|4|5|6|
```

I am getting lost how six is getting formed from 2's index. Can someone explain in an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every "ugly" number (except 1) can be formed by multiplying a smaller ugly number by 2, 3, or 5.

So let's say that the ugly numbers found so far are [1,2,3,4,5]. Based on that list we can generate three sequences of ugly numbers:

Multiplying by 2, the possible ugly numbers are [2,4,6,8,10]
Multiplying by 3, the possible ugly numbers are [3,6,9,12,15]
Multiplying by 5, the possible ugly numbers are [5,10,15,20,25]

But we already have 2,3,4, and 5 in the list, so we don't care about values less than or equal to 5. Let's mark those entries with a `-` to indicate that we don't care about them

Multiplying by 2, the possible ugly numbers are [-,-,6,8,10]
Multiplying by 3, the possible ugly numbers are [-,6,9,12,15]
Multiplying by 5, the possible ugly numbers are [-,10,15,20,25]

And in fact, all we really care about is the *smallest* number in each sequence

Multiplying by 2, the smallest number greater than 5 is 6
Multiplying by 3, the smallest number greater than 5 is 6
Multiplying by 5, the smallest number greater than 5 is 10

After adding 6 to the list of ugly numbers, each sequence has one additional element:

Multiplying by 2, the possible ugly numbers are [-,-,-,8,10,12]
Multiplying by 3, the possible ugly numbers are [-,-,9,12,15,18]
Multiplying by 5, the possible ugly numbers are [-,10,15,20,25,30]

But the elements from each sequence that are useful are:

Multiplying by 2, the smallest number greater than 6 is 8
Multiplying by 3, the smallest number greater than 6 is 9
Multiplying by 5, the smallest number greater than 6 is 10

So you can see that what the algorithm is doing is creating three sequences of ugly numbers. Each sequence is formed by multiplying all of the existing ugly numbers by one of the three factors.

But all we care about is the smallest number in each sequence (larger than the largest ugly number found so far).

So the indexes i2, i3, and i5 are the indexes into the corresponding sequences. When you use a number from a sequence, you update the index to point to the next number in that sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The intuition is the following:

- any *ugly number* can be written as the product between 2, 3 or 5 and another (smaller) *ugly number*.

With that in mind, the solution that is mentioned in the question keeps track of *i2*, *i3* and *i5*, the indices of the smallest ugly numbers generated so far, which multiplied by 2, 3, respectively 5 lead to a number that was not already generated. The smallest of these products is the smallest ugly number that was not already generated.

To state this differently, I believe that the following statement from the question might be the source of some confusion:

> The algorithm is to keep three different counter variable for a
>   multiple of 2, 3 and 5. Let's assume i2,i3, and i5.

Note, for example, that ugly[i2] is not necessarily a multiple of 2. It is simply the smallest ugly number for which 2 * ugly[i2] is greater than ugly[i] (the largest ugly number known so far).

---

Regarding how the number 6 is generated in the next step, the procedure is shown below:

```
ugly = |1|2|3|4|5

  i2 = 2;
  i3 = 1;
  i5 = 1;

ugly[5] = min(ugly[2]*2, ugly[1]*3, ugly[1]*5) = min(3*2, 2*3, 2*5) = 6

---------------------------------------------------

ugly = |1|2|3|4|5|6

  i2 = 3
  i3 = 2
  i5 = 1
```

Note that here both *i2* and *i3* need to be incremented after generating the number 6, because both i2*2, as well as i3*3 produced the same next smallest ugly number.

Comment: to find 6 as an ugly number, its doing ugly[2] *2. Which is 3*2 = 6 . I am not able to visualize how index count mapped to array works?

Comment: If i2=2 , why i have to see value in ugly[2] to get next multiple?

Comment: @Sumeet because ugly[2] is the smallest ugly number which, when multiplied by 2, leads to an ugly number that is larger than the last generated one (which is ugly[4] == 5). If, for example, we were to multiply ugly[1] * 2, then we would have got the value 4 (which was already generated). On the other hand, if we were to multiply, for example, ugly[3] * 2, we would have got the value 8 (which is larger than necessary, it can not be the next one in the sequence). This is why i2 == 2 indicates that we should try precisely ugly[i2] * 2, as a small candidate ugly number that was not generated yet.